# Can we reconstruct the system of equations form solution set?

Tags: linear-algebra, systems-of-equations

Lets consider three equations $$ 2x_1-x_2+5x_3 = 10$$  $$x_1+x_2-3x_3 = -2$$ $$2x_1+4x_2+x_3 = 1$$

the solution set for these equations is $ \begin{pmatrix} 2  \\ -1 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix} $

Is there any way reconstruct equations from the solution?

Comment: One system that has this solution is
$$
1x_1 + 0x_2 + 0x_3 = 2\\
0x_1 + 1x_2 + 0x_3 = -1\\
0x_1 + 0x_2 + 1x_3 = 1.
$$
Does this count as "reconstructing equations" from the solution?

Comment: No. You have a system $Ax = b,$ if you premultiply by _any_ invertible matrix $L$ then $LAx = Lb$ has exactly the same solutions. The system will be very likely be different from your original one.

Comment: @Ben Is it possible to go back to same equations if  I store or have some prior knowledge of system of equations?

Comment: @user1086, it depends of what "prior knowledge" you consider. But if will be essentially $\mathbf{x}$ and the full $\mathbf{A}$ matrix in $\mathbf{A}  \mathbf{x} = \mathbf{b}$. Add to the solutions by WillM a raft of systems with singular $\mathbf{A}$ (they can have an infinite number of solutions).

Comment: You can also think of this geometrically. You are saying there is an affine subspace of $\mathbf{R}^d$ and you _know_ a point in this affine subspace, and are asking about the equation (this is already ill-posed since there is no such thing as "the" equation of an affine subspace). Obviously, given a point, you cannot characterise the affine subspace. Not even in low dimensions, in $\mathbf{R}^2$ an affine subspace is a line and as such knowing one of its points cannot tell you anything about any equation defining the line. It gets worse as dimension increases (in some sense).

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the system as a matrix is the best way to approach this problem, as suggested by [@WillM.](https://math.stackexchange.com/users/396761/will-m) in the comments.

Here's a way to think about it graphically:

Setting $x_1,x_2,x_3$ as $x,y,z$ in the Cartesian coordinate system, each equation represents a plane and the point(s) common to all the planes is(are) the solution(s) to the system.

For any given point in the space(i.e. a "solution") there can be an infinite number of set of three planes intersecting at this exact point. So there is no way of associating a point to a single set of planes, i.e. a system. Given adequate conditions, it may be possible to determine a unique system.

Its also helpful to think about the same in the 2d plane. Infinite pairs of straight lines can intersect at any point in the plane(they're called a family).